# Replace `"{"` to `{"` from String in Apex

Tags: apex, integration, json, parsing

Please hear me out before marking this as duplicate or irrelevant.

I have done one integration and I am getting data something like this.

```
{
  "page_number": 1,
  "page_size": 10,
  "total_elements": 141,
  "last": false,
  "result": [
    {
      "triggered_at": 1563380205046,
      "user_id": "100-080-0982",
      "type": "freeform_content_push",
      "content": "{\"GCM\":\"{\\\"data\\\":{\\\"type\\\":\\\"content-push\\\",\\\"mode\\\":\\\"TAGGED\\\",\\\"content_type\\\":\\\"TEXT\\\",\\\"content\\\":\\\"the body\\\",\\\"title\\\":\\\"the title\\\",\\\"expiration\\\":null,\\\"deeplink\\\":null,\\\"template_id\\\":\\\"f8c29e89-253f-41df-8b7e-5d4a7ab8e539\\\"}}\",\"APNS\":\"{\\\"aps\\\":{\\\"content-available\\\":1},\\\"type\\\":\\\"content-push\\\",\\\"mode\\\":\\\"TAGGED\\\",\\\"content_type\\\":\\\"TEXT\\\",\\\"content\\\":\\\"the body\\\",\\\"title\\\":\\\"the title\\\",\\\"expiration\\\":null,\\\"deeplink\\\":null,\\\"template_id\\\":\\\"f8c29e89-253f-41df-8b7e-5d4a7ab8e539\\\"}\",\"APNS_SANDBOX\":\"{\\\"aps\\\":{\\\"content-available\\\":1},\\\"type\\\":\\\"content-push\\\",\\\"mode\\\":\\\"TAGGED\\\",\\\"content_type\\\":\\\"TEXT\\\",\\\"content\\\":\\\"the body\\\",\\\"title\\\":\\\"the title\\\",\\\"expiration\\\":null,\\\"deeplink\\\":null,\\\"template_id\\\":\\\"f8c29e89-253f-41df-8b7e-5d4a7ab8e539\\\"}\"}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I want to parse the `"content"` value but as you see the content is coming as `String`.
So first I have removed all the `\` characters from the payload.

Now I have something like this

```
"{"GCM":"{"data":{"type":"content-push","mode":"TAGGED","content_type":"TEXT","content":"the body","title":"the title","expiration":null,"deeplink":null,"template_id":"f8c29e89-253f-41df-8b7e-5d4a7ab8e539"}}","APNS":"{"aps":{"content-available":1},"type":"content-push","mode":"TAGGED","content_type":"TEXT","content":"the body","title":"the title","expiration":null,"deeplink":null,"template_id":"f8c29e89-253f-41df-8b7e-5d4a7ab8e539"}","APNS_SANDBOX":"{"aps":{"content-available":1},"type":"content-push","mode":"TAGGED","content_type":"TEXT","content":"the body","title":"the title","expiration":null,"deeplink":null,"template_id":"f8c29e89-253f-41df-8b7e-5d4a7ab8e539"}"}"}
```

There are few extra double qoutes in the given json and it will work if I will replace
`"{"` => `{"` and `}"` => `}`.

But whenever I am trying to do
`jsonResponse = jsonResponse.replaceAll('"{"', '{"');` this line it gives me an error

**FATAL_ERROR System.StringException: Invalid regex: Illegal repetition near index 0 "{"**

Please help me here. I have tried several ways to do this but still error only.

I you have some other and better way to parse this please let me know.

Thank you so much for your time and efforts.

Answer (score 6):

The system that is sending you this payload is broken. The best way to address this problem is to fix the remote system so that it sends proper JSON.

To address your question as asked, though: you are receiving this error because the first parameter of `replaceAll()` is a Java regular expression, not a string literal. The `{` character is being interpreted here as a quantifier, the start of an expression like `"{3}` which would match a character 3 times. You need to escape it with a backslash, which then gets an extra backslash when present in an Apex string literal since it too is a special character.

```
jsonResponse = jsonResponse.replaceAll('"\\{"', '{"');
```

Comment: Yes just now I also figured it out. 
Btw thanks for the help.
Yes I am aware of broken payload but its coming from third party and not in my hands so no other option than doing some workaround.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to deserialize the content again:

```
Map<String, Object> payload = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(responseJson);
List<Object> results = (List<Object>)payload.get('result');
for(Object result: results) {
    Map<String, Object> resultContent = (Map<String, Object>)result;
    Map<String, Object> content = JSON.deserializeUntyped((String)resultContent.get('content'));
}
```

You may be tempted to just use replaceAll and be done with it, but you **may break unexpectedly**. Anything other than using a JSON parser is asking for trouble. You have been warned.

Comment: I tried that way as well. but the payload is incorrect so I am getting error while deserializing it into Map.